# Get form data and store it into database using AJAX, on submit it gives me Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Get form data and store it into database using AJAX, on submit it gives me Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
$("#addRevenueForm").on("submit", event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var revenue = $("#revenueTextAdd");
        var month = $("#revenueMonthAdd");
        var unit = $("#revenueUnitAdd");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/settings/add_revenue_api/",
            data:{
                revenue:revenue,
                month:month,
                unit:unit,
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success:data => console.log("data =", data),
            error:error => console.log("error = ", error),
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `var revenue = $("#revenueTextAdd");` then `revenue` will hold a complete copy of jQuery wrapping the element with the ID `revenueTextAdd`, and may have circular references that cause the error message.

Change this to get the value instead:

```
var revenue = $("#revenueTextAdd").val();
```